# elasticsearch get specific fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to search data from following indexed data

```
   PUT /nested_test100/t/1
  {
    "title": "Nest eggs1",
    "body":  "Making your money work...",
    "tags":  [ "cash1", "shares1" ],
    "comments": [ 
      {
        "name":    "John Smith1",
        "comment": "Great article1",
        "age":     28,
        "stars":   1,
        "date":    "2014-09-01"
      },
      {
        "name":    "Alice White1",
        "comment": "More like this please1",
        "age":     31,
        "stars":   1,
        "date":    "2014-10-22"
      }
    ]
  }

  PUT /nested_test100/t/2
  {
    "title": "Nest eggs2",
    "body":  "Making your money work...",
    "tags":  [ "cash", "shares" ],
    "comments": [ 
      {
        "name":    "John Smith2",
        "comment": "Great article2",
        "age":     30,
        "stars":   2,
        "date":    "2014-09-01"
      },
      {
        "name":    "Alice White2",
        "comment": "More like this please2",
        "age":     31,
        "stars":   2,
        "date":    "2014-10-22"
      }
    ]
  }

  PUT /nested_test100/t/3
  {
    "title": "Nest eggs3",
    "body":  "Making your money work...",
    "tags":  [ "cash3", "shares3" ],
    "comments": [ 
      {
        "name":    "John Smith3",
        "comment": "Great article3",
        "age":     28,
        "stars":   3,
        "date":    "2014-09-01"
      },
      {
        "name":    "Alice White3",
        "comment": "More like this please3",
        "age":     30,
        "stars":   3,
        "date":    "2014-10-22"
      }
    ]
  }

  GET /nested_test100/t/_search
```

what I want is to get title, body tags only and only comments having age=28.

How I should write query dsl for that.

what I have written is following

```
POST /nested_test100/t/_search
{
  "fields" : ["title","comments.age","body","tags"],
  "query"  : {
             "term" : { "comments.age" : "28" }
           }
}
```

and its giving me data like this

```
     "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "nested_test100",
        "_type": "t",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "fields": {
           "comments.age": [
              28,
              31
           ],
           "title": [
              "Nest eggs1"
           ],
           "body": [
              "Making your money work..."
           ],
           "tags": [
              "cash1",
              "shares1"
           ]
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "nested_test100",
        "_type": "t",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1,
        "fields": {
           "comments.age": [
              28,
              30
           ],
           "title": [
              "Nest eggs3"
           ],
           "body": [
              "Making your money work..."
           ],
           "tags": [
              "cash3",
              "shares3"
           ]
        }
     }
  ]
```

but I don't want comments having age other than 28.

I am using elasticsearch version 1.7

Comment: You need to map `comments` as a `nested` type and use a `nested` query for that.

Comment: @val can you post your suggestion as proper answer so that I can try that.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `inner_hits` to include nested inner objects as inner hits to a search hit.

The search request would be like :

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "comments",
      "query": {
        "match": {"comments.age" : 28}
      },
      "inner_hits": {} 
    }
  }
}
```

P.S : You will need to map the comments as a nested field (as already mentioned by Val)

Comment: Also mention that the OP needs to map the `comments` field as `nested`

Comment: ERROR QueryParsingException[[nested_test100] [nested] nested object under path [comments] is not of nested type]; }]

Comment: You need to map comments as a nested field.

Comment: @nbirla The mapping is already created by elasticsearch  GET /nested_test100/t/_mapping and it does't contain nested type. How can I modify it now

Comment: Please refer to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-mapping.html